# DOMDocument->saveHTML isn't working as expected with href attributes

Tags: php, escaping, domdocument

I'm trying to parse some html with PHP in order to add some nodes, but output of DOMDocument->saveHTML isn't working as expected cause href attributes are encoded.

This is a simple code in order to check the wrong output:

```
$html = "<a href='javascript:console.log(\"klk\");'>click here</a>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $html );
echo $html . "\n";
echo "-----------------\n";
echo $doc->saveHTML( $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')[0] ) . "\n";
```

And here is the output:

```
<a href='javascript:console.log("klk");'>click here</a>
-----------------
<a href="javascript:console.log(%22klk%22);">click here</a>
```

As you can see something goes wrong with the href attributes.

Any idea about how can I solve this?

Test/play url: http://ideone.com/TsDhI3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing the HTML in the correct format, with values for attributes delimited by double quotes, not single ones, so they don't get encoded. Javascript recognises strings delimited by single quotes.

Here's an example:

```
 $html = '<a href="javascript:console.log(\'klk\');">click here</a>';
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML( $html );
 echo $html . "\n";
 echo "-----------------\n";
 echo $doc->saveHTML( $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')[0] ) . "\n";
```

Here's the working version - http://ideone.com/DjEyUX

Comment: This is just an example, the problem is that html comes from a lot of sources and I can't warranty how the html is created  ...

Comment: The DOMDocument() functionality is built for correct HTML. If your app gets its input from uncontrolled sources which give out garbled HTML, you should use an utility to clean it up before feeding it in. Libraries for this are http://htmlpurifier.org/docs or http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php